# How to nest more than 1 level route in Angular route?

Tags: angular6, angular-routing

i make an dashboard app for manage data using angular 6. but i stuck when i nest more than 1 lazyload route, it's not work, It's seem like can not add more than 1 lazyload route in angular router

My App routing :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SigninComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './core/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

my dashboard route

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [

      {
        path: 'products',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductModule'
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

My product route:

```
const productRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ProductEditComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'addproduct',
        component: ProductCreateComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(productRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

when i access localhost:4200/dashboard/products/id3 it take an error: can not match any route 'dashboard/products/id3'. I think i wrong some where in routing setup but i cant not find where is an error. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've create a page for you..Just check and do the changes accordingly. You need to check module path correctly otherwise it should work with no issue. You can change the url to hello.

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-nweyjt

// For eg.
// https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-nweyjt/hello/3
```

Comment: sr, it's still not working :< ex i go to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-nweyjt/hello/3 it's still come back to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-nweyjt

Comment: i'm really stuck in this problem :<

Comment: You are doing it wrongly. You need to click first URL and once stackblitz gets open completely, change the url in stackblitz browser not the main url. You can see output in their browser. Click on lazy link and then add hello and then id in that url

Comment: Oh im wrong , it's work now :d but can you explain more detail why it need to add a children array and in children need to redirectTo ?

Comment: Children are meant for internal routing not for routing to internal module since you are using lazy loading that module has not be there in browser and that is the reason route not found error was coming. Angular assumes that all its children routes are well defined but in your case it wasnt because of lazy loading.